# Method not intended for code attribute?

Tags: .net, vb.net, attributes

I have a couple of shared methods in my app which are intended to be used with ObjectDataSource's (and other reflection based objects).  They handle a lot of automatic parameter checking, filtering, etc.  They are, however, all one time use methods (they rebuild everything on every call).  It would be much better for someone writing code directly to call the instance methods so that all the filtering, etc, is stored between calls.

Is there an attribute I can add to my methods to indicate this?  The best would be if it would prevent the method from being called without reflection.  Second best would be to issue a warning that the method is being used wrong.

Here's a sample of what I want to acheive:

```
<MethodNotIntendedForCode()> _
Public Shared Function DataAccessMethod(Parameters....) As ObjectQuery(Of DataType)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
<Obsolete("This isn't the method you are looking for")>
```

which will create a warning if called in code. You can also use an option on `ObsoleteAttribute` to mark it as an **error** (at compile) if called directly.

The other option, obviously, is simply to make it non-public. Other useful attributes here include `EditorBrowsableAttribute` and `BrowsableAttribute`.

Comment: If I make it non-public will ODS still be able to access it via reflection?  Doesn't that defeat the purpose of making something non-public?  And also make it undiscoverable?

Comment: @just.another.programmer when you are using reflection, the sky is the limit. Whether ODS will **choose** to use non-public methods is entirely up to ODS

Comment: I have been playing around with the obsolete / browsable combos, they work really well for this.  Thanks!